# Nvidia GeForce driver issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I just updated my Nvidia GeForce driver via the Update Driver wizard in Windows 7 (windows says my driver is up to date version:8.17.12.7533); however, when I check on the Nvidia website, it states that "NVIDIA GeForce 280.26 WHQL Drivers Released".

What's the difference between these two versions of driver for GeForce GTX 560 Ti?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the drivers version via the Driver Update Wizard under Windows 7 etc. take the last 4 digits of the version number and add a decimal before the last 2 digits and you'll be able to compare with Nvidia's driver version system.

Comment: So, your current driver version is 8.17.1**2.7533**, which means 275.33. (formatting failed...)